# JDBC Comparison

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Here's my code:

```
            //Section 5, Execute Query
            asking = conn.createStatement();
            String Sql = "SELECT * FROM exercise4a";
            ResultSet rs = asking.executeQuery(Sql);

            //Section 6, Option 2
            //if(rs.isBeforeFirst())
            //{
                rs.next();
                int numRows = rs.getRow();

                String name = rs.getString("FirstName");
                for(int i = 0; i < numRows; i++)
                {
                    rs.next();
                    name = rs.getString("FirstName");
                    System.out.println("Test1");
                    System.out.println("Test1" + name);
                    if(name.equals(fName))
                    {
                        System.out.println("Test2");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        rs.next();
```

The issue I am having is comparing my input string (fName) to the database column(FirstName). For this project, I cannot modify the table in any way. The schema for FirstName is VARCHAR(50).

How can I compare a scanner String with a VARCHAR and return an output?

System.out.println("Test2); is a placeholder for printing comments, based on the FirstName column.

Comment: try trim and ignorecase with name.equals(fName)

Comment: I'm new to java, I don't suppose I can get an example please?

Comment: can you write here values of name and fName (from debug or System.out.print?)

Comment: name.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(fName.trim());

Comment: I am not entirely sure how JDBC is relevant for this question, except if the column is a `CHAR` instead of `VARCHAR`, as `CHAR` is padded with spaces. Otherwise you simply compare strings the way you would any other string in Java.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel JDBC is being used to pull information from a MySQL Database. I elected to trim the preceding code to clean the post up.
According to [link]http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-data-types.htm, VARCHAR (the column schema) can be used in java as a string.

Comment: @BenignReaver You use JDBC, but that is not really relevant: a string is a string in Java. The only reasons equality fail are difference in content. You need to find out 1) what the difference is, eg extra whitespace, similar looking chars with different codepoints, etc (you fail to mention the actual values in the question) and 2) find the cause for that difference. I admit that for (2), it might have to do with storage in MySQL or the handling by the JDBC driver, but unless you clearly demonstrate that, it is not really relevant for the question as demonstrated by the answer you accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
if(name.equals(fName))
```

With

```
if(name.trim().equalsIgnoreCase(fName.trim()))
```

The `trim()` function removes any leading/trailing whitespaces from the `String` value. Then the `equals()` changes to `equalsIgnoreCase()`, which as you would guess, checks if the `String` values are the same without comparing case.